# Can S-Video drive HDTV?

Tags: video, htpc

The High-Def TV I'm trying to use is an older model, without HDMI, and more importantly, without a digital tuner built-in. My HTPC has an S-Video out, and the video card actually includes an S-Video to Component converter cable.

My question is: can the S-Video output on my video card drive 720p and 1080i video for the TV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the ones that include a component converter aren't actually s-video, but a proprietary connection that uses a similar shape/plug.

Take a look at the closeups in the picture below.  The one labeled "A" is S-Video; notice it only has 4 pins... If you have a "B", you are in luck!

[image: TV-Out via round plugs]

So most likely, that port can drive the 720p and 1080i on the HDTV, provided you are using the cable that came with the card (nvidia and ati cards have different standards from my experiance).

Comment: Thanks! So that round "B" port is really just a way to get component video out of the card without actually having 3 separate jacks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video says that they are still technically considered s-video, and it lits some of the pin-outs for graphics cards.   apparently there are 7 and 9 pin versions, both of which are potentially capable of component RGB

Answer (score 2):

#### No

But as [Ape-inago](https://superuser.com/users/9954/ape-inago) points out, if the output is not really [Separate Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-video) then you win.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late getting to the party here, but I thought it would also be helpful to point out that you can get VGA-to-component video cables, if your video card does not have a special port/adapter for component video.